# Keylogger but when i press esc its doesnt get out

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a keylogger. The script is nice until I press esc. But it doesn't exit. I did write a code for it but doesn't work. I tried so many options but I couldn't do it.

```py
import pynput.keyboard

keys = []

escape = ['Esc' , 'Key.esc' , 'p' , 'Key.shift']

def on_press(letters):
    global keys 
    keys.append(letters)
    print(letters)

    
for k in keys:
    if k == escape:
        exit()

listening = pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press)

with listening:
    listening.join()
```

I did try:

```py
for k in keys:
    if k.find(escape):
        rapor.write(keys)
```

and just like this options. I was expecting when I press button of in `escape`, escape from the program.

Comment: I never used this module, but I'm pretty sure " if k in escape: " (in instead of ==) would have more chance of working.

Comment: its didnt help  . i tried before

Answer (score 1):

You only check for escape once before you populate keys

```py
import pynput.keyboard

keys = []
escape = ['Esc' , 'Key.esc' , 'p' , 'Key.shift']

def on_press(letters):
    global keys 
    keys.append(letters)
    print(letters)
# at this point keys is empty
for k in keys:
    if k == escape:
        exit()

#only after this keys starts to get values
listening = pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press)

with listening:
    listening.join()
```

you need to check for the escape key in `on_press` something along the lines of this:

```py
def on_press(letters):
    global keys
    if letters in escape:
        exit()
    keys.append(letters)
    print(letters)
```

Also your `escape` is wrong you probably want something like:

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Key
escape = [Key.esc, Key.shift]
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. Did you try it?

Comment: Thanks for the share. But its didnt help me. youre did help me about the follow.

Comment: Right, didn't notice the `escape` list was wrong too. Fixed it

Comment: Its gave me error called "ImportError: cannot import name "Keys" " . btw i fixed the list.

Comment: I don't get that. Oh, but, you didn't copy the `import` from this answer.

Comment: i didnt understand what did you mean?

Comment: how can i add a script again?

Comment: Surely you should just copy and paste the code from this answer. But I suspect you looked at the code and typed it in, and there you made your mistake.

Comment: yes. i looked at the code and i typed in my ide. but i dont know where i did a mistake?? any way i changed the import part.                                                                                                '''from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller'''

Comment: then its gave me a error called Name error in 18 line about pynput.

Comment: you don't change the import cause you still need the other one just add it. Or use `pynput.keyboard.Key` instead of `Key` and use the old import.

Comment: then its gave 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named pynput.keyboard.Key'

Comment: You should probably refresh your knowledge of the [python import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

Comment: thanks... i think i will another project. but youre right i should refresh my knowledge about import system and python..